# Java Client-Server Application only works at local network

Tags: java, android, localhost

I made a simple java client-server application, where the client (android mobile) send messages to the server (pc), however both of them are connected to the same network. How can I do the same service through the internet instead of localhost? Using 3G at my mobile, for example.
I tried using my public IP as well but it didn't work.
My server is just like that:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PCServer {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5000);

        Socket client = server.accept();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }

        s.close();
        server.close();
        client.close();     
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are plenty of services that will host your application for you.

Comment: Long story short, problem is that your server is not visible from network outside of your local network because of router/firewall settings. You can configure your settings, get static IP and get DNS (if you want to use domain names) to make your server work, but its a hassle for beginners.
Amazon AWS and Heroku provides cloud services that are easily usable so you don't have to concern about those configurations and also security issues.

Answer (score 1):

To access your localhost from outside of your network you have to do few things

1. In Firewall: allow incoming connections on the port that your server listening for.
2. In your local router: forward all inbound connections to the required port on to the IP of the local computer with the same port.
3. Replace the localhost with your public IP in the client application.

Note: To make this solution usable you should have a static IP so you can rely on it and use it inside you client application.

Answer (score 1):

When you say your *public IP* I presume you mean the public IP as expressed by your desktop browser when you hit a website like [What is my ip](http://whatismyip.com)

This has nothing to do with Java or Android.

- Your ISP will not give your PC (or even your router) a public IP. Even if it does, it will be [NATed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).
- If you want to be able to do this then you need to contact your ISP to get a public IP address. Usually it will be static but not always and you may have to specifically ask for it.
- Then you have to configure your own gear to handle and route the
  public requests to your PC.

Or, you can just use [Heroku](http://heroku.com) and call it good.